# IQuery NHibernate - does it HAVE to be a list?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Can I return it as an object if I am doing a

```
Select OneItem from Table Where OtherItem = "blah"?
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I am building a constructor to return an object based on its name rather than its ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`query.UniqueResult<T>()` returns just one **T**

Answer (score 1):

If there's more than one potential result, then `query.FirstResult()` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Or using LINQ you can have `query.First()`, `query.SingleOrDefault()`, `query.Min(predicate)` etc...